# Is the polynomial system representation of a symmetric cipher overdetermined?

Tags: symmetric

Is the representation of the polynomial system of a symmetric cipher overdetermined?

Comment: It seems trivial to make an overdetermined system of equations from one that is not. Perhaps the real question is: _Can the conventional_ representation of the polynomial system of a symmetric cipher _be_ overdetermined? Otherwise, I don't get it.

Comment: Some examples or references could help making the question more clear. As it stands it is not clear to me what the definition of "overdetermined" is, or when this happens. Without this clarity the question is in danger of being opinionated.